# N-body simulation using openMP in C

Tags: c, concurrency, openmp, simulation

I have programmed a simulation for the n-body simulation using openMP, where each process represents a single mass Point.
The program compiles fine at the moment, but as you can see, I have several print functions to check the output of individual functions (for example, the accl_a(), which calculates the acceleration of a mass point).

During one of these "control" print functions, I noticed that I'm getting the same value for accelerations[0] and accelerations[1], which represent the x and y coordinates, respectively, regardless of different x,y coordinates. This also causes me to get the same values for the velocity[0] and velocity[1].

I have looked over and am unfortunately unable to find the reason for this, so any help (and generally any tips for improvement) are welcome, as I am somewhat of a beginner!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define NUM_POINTS 3


// mass Point struct with mass, current pos, & velocity/acceleration arr to store x,y changes

typedef struct massPoint{
    float mass;
    float x, y;
    float velocity[2];
    float acceleration[2];
} massPoint;

// init mass points

void initMassPoint(struct massPoint* point){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int i;

    point->mass = ((float)(rand() % (10000 + 1))/(float)(rand() % (10000 + 1))) * 100;
    point->x = rand() % 200 + 1;
    point->y = rand() % 200 + 1;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
        point->acceleration[i] = 0;
        point->velocity[i] = 0;
    }
}

//calculates acceleration of struct a, coordinate x/y

void accel_a(struct massPoint* a, struct massPoint* b, char coordinate){
    float grav_constant = 6.67/1e11;
    float distance, acceleration;

    distance = sqrt( pow((b->x - a->x), 2) + pow((b->y - a->y), 2));
    if(coordinate == 'x'){
        acceleration = a->mass + (grav_constant * a->mass / distance) * (b->x - a->x);
        a->acceleration[0] += acceleration;
    }
    else if(coordinate == 'y'){
        acceleration = a->mass + (grav_constant * a->mass / distance) * (b->y - a->y);
        a->acceleration[1] += acceleration;
    }
    
}

//calculates new velocity of point a, coorindate x/y

void vel_new(struct massPoint* a, char coordinate){
    float new_vel;
    if(coordinate == 'x'){
        new_vel = a->velocity[0] + a->acceleration[0];
        a->velocity[0] = new_vel;
    }
    else if(coordinate == 'y'){
        new_vel = a->velocity[1] + a->acceleration[1];
        a->velocity[1] = new_vel;
    }
}

//calculates new pos of point a in coordinate x/y
void new_position(struct massPoint* a, char coordinate){
    float new_pos;

    if(coordinate == 'x'){
        new_pos = a->x + a->velocity[0];
        a->x = new_pos;
    }
    else if(coordinate == 'y'){
        new_pos = a->y + a->velocity[1];
        a->y = new_pos;
    }
}


int main(){
    
    struct massPoint points[NUM_POINTS];
    int i;

    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NUM_POINTS)
    {
        //init as many points as (NUM_POINTS) & store in arr points

        int id;
        id = omp_get_thread_num();
        initMassPoint(&points[id]);
        
        #pragma omp barrier //wait until all points succ. initialized, print starting var. of each point

        printf("Mass Point %d: mass=%.2f, x=%f, y=%f\n", id, points[id].mass, points[id].x, points[id].y);
        for(i = 0; i < NUM_POINTS; i++){
            if(id != i){
                #pragma omp critical 
                {
                    accel_a(&points[id], &points[i], 'x');
                    accel_a(&points[id], &points[i], 'y');
                    
                }   
            }
        }
        #pragma omp barrier

        printf("New acceleration for Mass Point %d: x=%f, y=%f\n", id, points[id].acceleration[0], points[id].acceleration[1]);
        vel_new(&points[id], 'x');
        vel_new(&points[id], 'y');
        printf("vel for %d x = %f, y = %f \n", id, points[id].velocity[0], points[id].velocity[1]);
        
        #pragma omp barrier

        new_position(&points[id], 'x');
        new_position(&points[id], 'y');
        //printf("new coordinates for Point %d are: x = %f, y = %f \n", id, points[id].x, points[id].y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, do not do `sqrt( pow((b->x - a->x), 2) + pow((b->y - a->y), 2))`. `pow(foo, 2)` is inefficient (unless the compiler optimizes it), and there is a standard function for this: `distance = hypot(b->x - a->x, b->y - a->y);`.

Comment: `point->mass = ((float)(rand() % (10000 + 1))/(float)(rand() % (10000 + 1))) * 100;
    point->x = rand() % 200 + 1;` is suspicious. Why does one use the form `rand() % (x+1)` and the other use `rand () % x + 1`? That could give a division by zero, and it is more likely you would want mass to be non-zero and allow position to be zero than the other way around. And what is the purpose of dividing one random number by another—what probability distribution do you think that gives, and what distribution do you want?

Comment: Your acceleration calculations look wonky. I would not be surprised if `a->mass` dominates it, since `grav_constant` makes the other term small. The acceleration caused on body A by body B is not the mass of A plus something else. The total magnitude is G•Ma•Mb/r^2, and then you can break it into x and y components. You will need to rewrite the code for that.

Comment: Make the problem reproducible. Stop using `time` for `srand`. Get code for a simple random-number generator somewhere and put it into your program in place of `rand` and `srand`. The purpose of that is to give a specific random number generator so that other people can reproduce the problem without needing the `rand` in your C environment. Then set the seed to 1. If that does not reproduce the problem, try other seeds until you find one that reproduces the problem. That should give you a complete program that will reproduce the problem for other people.

Comment: Once you have code that reproduces the problem in a controlled way, examine the results of each calculation to see whether they produce the results you intend.

Comment: Creating a thread for each particle is a horrible idea. The cost of thread creation is non-trivial...

Comment: Your handling of coordinates is chaotic. Why `float x, y` for position and arrays for everything else? My advice, forget `x` and `y` and go with arrays throughout.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of the comments given to your question. Here a few more detailed comments that would not fit into a comment.

Compiling and executing the code on my system, I get identical values for all three points. Since you initialize the rng at the beginning of each initMassPoint call, you will get the same sequence of values for each point (unless the clock ticks by chance). If the rng maintains a state per thread, initializing the seed with the thread id should give you different and still reproducible values. On my system, initializing with `srand(omp_get_thread_num()+1);` already gave me reproducible initialization.

Compiling the code with ThreadSanitizer flag, the tool reports several data races in the code.

```
$ clang -g -fopenmp test_n_body.c -fsanitize=thread -lm
$ ./a.out
Mass Point 0: mass=463.66, x=54.000000, y=71.000000
Mass Point 1: mass=463.66, x=54.000000, y=71.000000
Mass Point 2: mass=463.66, x=54.000000, y=71.000000
LLVMSymbolizer: error reading file: No such file or directory
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=142859)
  Write of size 4 at 0x7ffd85f402ec by thread T1:
    #0 .omp_outlined._debug__ test_n_body.c:98:15 (a.out+0xd445d)
    #1 .omp_outlined. test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd4785)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xc2cf2)
    #3 main test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd42f8)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x7ffd85f402ec by main thread:
    #0 .omp_outlined._debug__ test_n_body.c:98:15 (a.out+0xd445d)
    #1 .omp_outlined. test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd4785)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xc2cf2)
    #3 main test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd42f8)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '??' at 0x7ffd85f21000 ([stack]+0x1f2ec)

  Thread T1 (tid=142861, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1022:3 (a.out+0x2b20d)
    #1 __kmp_create_worker <null> (libomp.so+0xa0da6)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race test_n_body.c:98:15 in .omp_outlined._debug__
==================
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=142859)
  Write of size 4 at 0x7ffd85f402ec by main thread:
    #0 .omp_outlined._debug__ test_n_body.c:98:37 (a.out+0xd456a)
    #1 .omp_outlined. test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd4785)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xc2cf2)
    #3 main test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd42f8)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x7ffd85f402ec by thread T2:
    #0 .omp_outlined._debug__ test_n_body.c:98:15 (a.out+0xd445d)
    #1 .omp_outlined. test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd4785)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xc2cf2)
    #3 main test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd42f8)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '??' at 0x7ffd85f21000 ([stack]+0x1f2ec)

  Thread T2 (tid=142862, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1022:3 (a.out+0x2b20d)
    #1 __kmp_create_worker <null> (libomp.so+0xa0da6)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race test_n_body.c:98:37 in .omp_outlined._debug__
==================
==================
WARNING: ThreadSanitizer: data race (pid=142859)
  Write of size 4 at 0x7ffd85f402ec by thread T1:
    #0 .omp_outlined._debug__ test_n_body.c:98:37 (a.out+0xd456a)
    #1 .omp_outlined. test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd4785)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xc2cf2)
    #3 main test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd42f8)

  Previous write of size 4 at 0x7ffd85f402ec by thread T2:
    #0 .omp_outlined._debug__ test_n_body.c:98:37 (a.out+0xd456a)
    #1 .omp_outlined. test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd4785)
    #2 __kmp_invoke_microtask <null> (libomp.so+0xc2cf2)
    #3 main test_n_body.c:87:5 (a.out+0xd42f8)

  Location is stack of main thread.

  Location is global '??' at 0x7ffd85f21000 ([stack]+0x1f2ec)

  Thread T1 (tid=142861, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1022:3 (a.out+0x2b20d)
    #1 __kmp_create_worker <null> (libomp.so+0xa0da6)

  Thread T2 (tid=142862, running) created by main thread at:
    #0 pthread_create tsan_interceptors_posix.cpp:1022:3 (a.out+0x2b20d)
    #1 __kmp_create_worker <null> (libomp.so+0xa0da6)

SUMMARY: ThreadSanitizer: data race test_n_body.c:98:37 in .omp_outlined._debug__
==================
New acceleration for Mass Point 1: x=-nan, y=-nan
vel for 1 x = -nan, y = -nan 
New acceleration for Mass Point 2: x=-nan, y=-nan
vel for 2 x = -nan, y = -nan 
New acceleration for Mass Point 0: x=-nan, y=-nan
vel for 0 x = -nan, y = -nan 
ThreadSanitizer: reported 3 warnings
```

All three reported races are on the loop variable i in the header of the for-loop. The threads concurrently initialize the shared variable to 0. Then there is a race between one thread initializing to 0 and another thread incrementing 1; and finally, some threads concurrently increment i.

Marking the variable as `private(i)` on the parallel directive fixes the issue.

Another issue with the code is the critical region in line 100. This critical region effectively serializes the code, so that you don't have any parallelism for this code section. Changing the access pattern, so that only one thread writes to each particle, but reads from multiple other particles should help to avoid the critical.